# “Strings” utility including linefeed (LF) and carrier return (CR)

Tags: linux, windows, sysinternals

I want to filter a large file (a raw partition image) for strings (an accidentally deleted text file). The normal "strings" utility (Linux GNU strings or Windows sysinternals strings) does not count CR and LF as parts of a string but as a seperator of strings. I need them to NOT be treated as a seperator. Is there any tool capable of this? A Windows tool would be great, but if I need to I can use a live-Linux.

thank you

PS: undelete toools cannot find this file

EDIT: As many of you did not understand me, let me try to explain again:

The string "test\ntext" with \n being newline (windows or unix) is treated by strings utility as "test" and "text". If I look for strings with a low number of chars there are a lot of "false positives" - just small strings from a binary or something else. As I want to search for text files (or fragments) the number of chars is large, which is good as many false positives can be removed from the list.
BUT: Textfiles have newlines in it and standard strings utility (GNU or sysinternals) does not "see" those as a single string.

I think

> -w
>   --include-all-whitespace
>   By default tab and space characters are included in the strings that are
>   displayed, but other whitespace characters, such a newlines and carriage
>   returns, are not. The -w option changes this so that all whitespace 
>   characters are considered to be part of a string.

is the solution, but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: you write "linux oder windows sysinternals" <-- what on earth does that mean?

Comment: I fixed it to linux strings or windows sysinternals strings , because I guess that's what you meant. Though re what you then wrote about CR and LF.. Are you sure?.  I don't know about strings, Linux uses LF as a line terminator(no CR), and doesn't use separators. Windows uses CRLF as line separator(no terminators).  But I get the general idea. you want a strings that coutns CR and LF as parts of a string.

Comment: I'm thinking that it won't work that way. it is debateable whether a text file is one unending string, or a series of smaller strings separated by a delimiter. Either way, the strings.exe output for a text file where the file was treated as a single blob would be indistinguishable from the output if it were considered a series of strings. since the bytes are encoded for output the delimiter character becomes a line break in the output. Now if you are asking about literal \r or \n strings, then that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you're using latest GNU strings. Grab it here:" https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/.  Compile, and use strings's -w option...

Comment: Its pretty hard to google for something with a very genric name like "strings" and the man pages I looked ad did not include the -w option. How long is this option available in GNU strings?!
I think this is the solution. Thank you.

Comment: he did tag this windows. Is this a windows program if so, where is it downloaded?  I notice that binutils is not a gnuwin32 package