# Is there an equivalent of "non breaking spaces" for line breaks?

Tags: microsoft-office, libreoffice

Non-breaking spaces are a small piece of whitespace that can be used to keep two words united in a line.

In Microsoft Word or Libre Office Writer, how do people use line feeding/breaking in a way that it'd try hard to keep two lines united in a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has a "keep lines together" option. Look under the section "keep paragraphs together" at [Keep text together](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d) to see how to use it.

> If two consecutive paragraphs or a subhead and a paragraph are closely related, you might want to keep them on the same page.
>
> 1. Right-click the paragraph or subhead that you want to keep with the content that follows it. In the box that opens, select `Paragraph`.
>      [image: Click the Paragraph option.]
> 2. In the `Paragraph` dialog box, click the `Line and Page Breaks` tab.
> 3. In the `Pagination` section, select the `Keep lines together` check box, and click OK.
>
>    [image]

LibreOffice Writer has a similar setting, per a comment by [JimK](https://superuser.com/users/541756/jim-k), for LibreOffice it is a paragraph setting as well: `Format -> Paragraph -> Text Flow -> Keep with Next Paragraph`, and/or `Do not split paragraph`.

You can see an example of the dialogue at [Techrepublic: How to enable split paragraphs in LibreOffice Writer](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-split-paragraphs-in-libreoffice-writer/), with instructions slightly paraphrased below.

> 1. Right-click the text and select `Edit Style`.
> 2. In the `Paragraph Style` window, click `Text Flow` tab and look for the `Options` section. Here you want to make sure to check/uncheck the `Do not split paragraph` and `Keep with next paragraph` checkboxes as required
>
> [image]

Comment: The answer for LibreOffice is a paragraph setting as well: *Format -> Paragraph -> Text Flow -> Keep with Next Paragraph*, or *Do not split paragraph*.

Comment: @JimK Thanks for letting me know, I have added it to my answer.

Comment: thank you both, you are very much too kind ‍♀️

Comment: @174140 thank you very much for the bounty. Glad we got you a solution.

Answer (score -1):

The question doesn't mention office at all. So I answered for plain text. Now I see though that the tags refer to office.

I'll keep the answer posted as is, but it responds to the question as if it were for plain text, which may be relevant to others reading the question.

Really any questioner if asking about "Office" should write that in the question not just in the tag.  A tag is to help with search, not to provide context for reading the question.

> nonbreaking spaces is a small piece of whitespace that tries hard to
>   keep two words united in a line.

For one thing, a non-breaking space when i've seen them, have been the same size as a regular space..

And another thing, what is this "tries hard". That doesn't mean anything

And it doesn't just work for two words. There could be just a letter on each side of a sequence of non-breaking spaces, or even, the whole line could start with a sequence of non-breaking spaces followed by a new line. So no it doesn't have to even separate things.

You are making up definitions that are completely inaccurate and meaningless and wrong.

> Now how do people use line feeding/breaking in a way that it'd try
>   hard to keep two lines united in a page?

If you look at an ascii chart, you'd see that you have characters and line breaks, no pages. You see pages if you try to use something like Ms Word. And if using a word processor, you can change the font size to try to keep lines on a page.

Lines exist at a more fundamental level than "pages".

Also, by the way, there's a difference between line separators and line endings, for example in one OS it may be a line separator, in another, a line terminator.  If it's a line separator, then when a file has one line , then it doesn't need a line separator at the end. If it is a line terminator, then every line must/should end in one.  "Linux uses LF as a line terminator(no CR), and doesn't use separators. Windows uses CRLF as line separator(no terminators)"  [1]

[1] (a quote from my comment in 2015 here) [“Strings” utility including linefeed (LF) and carrier return (CR)](https://superuser.com/questions/1009351/strings-utility-including-linefeed-lf-and-carrier-return-cr)